# More than one equation in DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

Is it possible to use more than one equation in `DSolve`, only one having a differential term? Or is it just the syntax with the below system? Thanks in advance! :)

```
  DSolve[{
     λbar s f0[s] - μ p f1[s] + (1 - pe) λbar s f1[s] 
      == λbar (p00 + (1 - pe) p10), 
      λ f0[s] + λbar s f0[s] + (1 - pe) λbar s f1[s] + 
      (1 - pe) λbar  f1[s] + (1 - pe) λbar s f1'[s] - μ f1[s] ==
       λbar (p00 + (1 - pe) p10)}, f0[s], f1[s], s]
```

Comment: Try `DSolve[(* equations *), {f0[s], f1[s]}, s]`.

Comment: Nope, i tried but again nothing @J.M.

Comment: @akin What you mean by nothing?

Comment: I mean, I get no results @MMM  It just rewrites my equation as the output

Comment: The [DSolve tutorials](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveOverview.html) seem to imply that `DSolve` handles linear DAEs with ***constant*** coefficients and perhaps only those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate `f0[s]` from your two equations and you will end up with one,

```
eq1 = λbar s f0[s] - μ p f1[s] + (1 - pe) λbar s f1[s] == λbar (p00 + (1 - pe) p10);

eq2 = λ f0[s] + λbar s f0[s] + (1 - pe) λbar s f1[s] + (1 - pe) λbar f1[s] 
     + (1 - pe) λbar s f1'[s] - μ f1[s] == λbar (p00 + (1 - pe) p10)

neweq = Eliminate[{eq1, eq2}, f0[s]]

DSolve[neweq, f1[s], s]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MMM it works, but it does not yield a product form solution. A pages-long output which does not imply f1(s) or f0(s).

Comment: @akin I am confused. Once you eliminate `f0[s]`, you will have only equation for `f1[s]`. "Pages-long" ????

Comment: I mean, no solution for f1(s). just pages long rewriting.

Comment: Actually, I don't get the same results as yours. Maybe, my mistake is about the execution or the output format?

Comment: @akin Restart your Kernel and run again your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot again @MMM . Yes, i get the result now. But when I do the reverse: eliminating f1(s), solving for f0(s). then I don't get a solution?

Comment: @akin you cannot eliminate `f1[s]` because it's derivative is involved.

Comment: @ MMM Aha, i see :) Any idea for finding a solution for f0(s), too?

Comment: @akin I would use `Solve` instead of `Eliminate`: ``sol = Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {f0[s], f1'[s]}]; dsol = DSolve[sol[[1, 2]] /. Rule -> Equal, {f1[s]}, s]; Join[{sol[[1, 1]] /. dsol}, dsol, 2]``.  Apply `FullSimplify` to shorten the expressions.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2, it works! I get a solution. But I don't understand what C[1] means and also the terms afterwards C[1]? How should i clean the solution?

Comment: @akin `C[1]` is the constant of integration. To have a particular solution you need to provide an initial condition.

Comment: @akin If you want to use the general solution many times, you can also substitute a number for `C[1]` after the fact with something like `solution /. C[1] -> 7`.  Or you can solve for it like this: `s0 = 2; Solve[f1[s] == 5 /. solution /. s -> s0, C[1]]`.  Replace `s0` (or `2`) and `5` by appropriate quantities.